# \rceil over multiple symbols

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I would like to write a `\rceil` over multiple symbols, like this:

[image]

With `K \frac{a_{n - \lfloor t\rfloor}}{a_{n\rceil}}` I managed to write:

[image]

I would like to have `n - \lfloor t\rfloor` in the numerator under a `\rceil`. I looked online, without success. `a_\rceil{n - \lfloor t\rfloor}` does not help.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for the [actuarialsymbol package](https://ctan.org/pkg/actuarialsymbol?lang=en)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I have used the package `actuarialangle` with the command `\actuarialangle{abc}`.  If you prefer to have rounded corners you can choose   `actuarialsymbol` package as written by
@mickep.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{actuarialangle}


\begin{document}
$K \frac{a_{\actuarialangle{n - \lfloor t\rfloor}}}{a_{\actuarialangle{n}}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, that's what I was looking for!

Comment: @AntoineSoetewey Welcome. :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can define the macro `\overceil` like this:

```
\def\overceil#1{\mathpalette\overceilA{#1}}
\def\overceilA#1#2{\setbox0=\hbox{$#1\overline{#2\;}$}\dimen0=\dimexpr\ht0-.1ex 
   \box0 \kern-.4pt \vrule height\dimen0 depth-.4ex}

test:
$$
  K {a_{\overceil{n - \lfloor t\rfloor}}\over a_{\overceil n}} 
$$

\bye
```

[image: overceil]